# Where to start with Enterprise OSGi development

Tags: java, ide, osgi

I would like to start developing enterprise applications using OSGi.

I have failed to find a COMPLETE explanation of what Tech Stack to employ, development tools to use, etc.

I am willing to put in the effort to learn and investigate this technology, however...

where do i start?

I would like to develop OSGi applications that expose REST webservices.

Once I have selected an OSGi implementation, what IDE can I use, can I use MAVEN, how do I use MAVEN, what Java EE servers can I use? Do I have to use Java EE Servers? where does Bndtools fit in?

What's best?

Apache Felix, Concierge OSGi, Equinox OSGi, Hitachi SuperJ, Knopflerfish, 
ProSyst mBS, Eclipse Gemini.

Comment: Where do i get help with this type of issue then? I am not lazy and want everybody to do my work for me!. I just need somewhere to start. Why cant SO do that for me?

Comment: BackSlash, Seelenvirtuose, Uwe Plonus, Holger, Donal; five SO experts can take the time to close my off topic question. nobody has the time to help. This is a genuine situation where I need assistance where more time has been allocated to editing and closing my question than trying to help me. Discuss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should stop where you started :). OSGi and Java EE are not really good friends. There are really good alternatives to Java EE technologies that are more simple and easier to use. They are more OSGi friendly as they have no, or not that many magical solutions. Some examples:

- Injection -> Declarative Services
- JPA -> Liquibase + QueryDSL
- JSF -> Thymeleaf

If you really want to, here are some hints:

Java EE servers__

Most of the Java EE servers nowadays support OSGi. E.g.: You can develop OSGi bundles and drop them to Glassfish and you can use Java EE related technologies in these bundles (JSF, JPA, ...).

You can find tutorials if you look for the name of the Java EE server and OSGi.

**OSGi enterprise specification and implementations**

OSGi has a separate specification to integrate Java EE related technologies like JPA. The chapters of this specification is implemented by [Apache Aries](http://aries.apache.org/). On the website of Aries, you will find examples. It also has samples in its source repository.

**Books**

There is a book called [Enterprise OSGi in Action](http://www.manning.com/cummins/). I have not read it, but it might worth checking it before getting started.

Comment: Balazs Zsoldos, thanks very much for looking at this. I have both Enterprise OSGi in Action & OSGi in Action, however i wanted to get my hands dirty creating code and trying OSGi out and these books are very good at explaining OSGi, just not giving example code labs for the current OSGi version

Comment: I suggest to set up a WAB (OSGi WAR) project and go from there.